# Is it possible to create multiple logcat windows in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, filtering, logcat, log-viewer

Is it possible to create multiple logcat windows in Android Studio for single attached device, so that I can filter different tags in different windows yet able to see together. How to do that?

Comment: NO. That is not possible. but you can add your filters from "Edit Filter Configuration". Then you can switch between your filters very easily.

Comment: May be not in Android Studio but you can create seperate logcat by using adb e.g. adb logcat

Comment: @SahilManchanda you mean in command line right?

Comment: Yep from the command line

Comment: @SahilManchanda yes I know.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat

Comment: @SagarNayak my question was about Android Studio, not command line.